# What is the expected maximum value of a gamma distribution, as a function of number of samples?

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution, extreme-value

I have the following situation. I have observations that fill out a gamma distribution. (At least they seem to: the distribution of values of several thousand observations looks to the eye like a gamma distribution. For the purposes of this question, let's assume they do.) I want to know what the largest value I can expect is, as a function of the number of observations I make, i.e. the expectation value of the extreme value.

I know that the more observations I make, the larger the largest value is likely to be, but I don't know how much larger. E.g. if I make 10 observations, the largest value I see might be 1; if I make 100 observations, it might be 1.5, etc. But what if I were to imagine making a very large number (e.g. 1e10) observations? I am reasonably sure this question is related to extreme-value theory, but I have not been able to answer it through reading/searching.

I did find a nice paper that showed that the expectation value of the max of a gaussian distribution is given by norm.ppf(0.5264**(1/n)), where n is the number of samples. I am looking for a similar expression for when the distribution is gamma, instead of gaussian. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The density of the largest value of a set of $n$ iid random variables $X_1,X_2,...X_n$  with common density $f_X$ and cdf $F_X$ (i.e. the  density of $Y=\max(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$) is

$$f_Y(y) = n f_X(y) F_X(y)^{n-1}$$


So the expectation is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} n\, y\, f_X(y)\, F_X(y)^{n-1} dy$.

The problem boils down to finding a suitable approximation to the integral. Of course for sufficiently large $n$ you can apply the Fisher-Tippet-Gnedenko theorem but you would then need to identify the values $a_n$ and $b_n$ as functions of $n$ ... which the expectation would be a function of

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that this is extreme value theory.

From the work shown here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063275/is-there-an-equation-for-the-maximum-of-n-random-draws-from-a-gamma-distribution/2063304#2063304) and other sites we know the appropriate extreme value distribution for the gamma case is the Gumbel distribution.

Using that development, we have the asymptotic result that if $M_n$ is defined as $$M_n = \textrm{Max} \left(X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n \right) $$ where $X_i \sim \mathrm{Gamma} \left( \mathrm{shape}=\alpha , \ \mathrm{scale} =1 \right)$ and the cdf is $F(x)$ with inverse cdf $F^{-1}(x),$ then
$$E[M_n] \approx \left[1 +\frac{\alpha-1}{F^{-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}   \right] \gamma \ + \ {F^{-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)} ,  $$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

If you have a scale parameter $\beta>0$ that is not equal to one you can multiply the above by $\beta$ as you would expect.